# Sequential Forward Selection (SFS) algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, vector, struct

I'm trying to implement the `SFS` algorithm `pages 11-12` of [this](http://research.cs.tamu.edu/prism/lectures/pr/pr_l11.pdf) document.

What I have so far in `C++` is the following:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

struct Features
{
    int m_f1;
    int m_f2;
    int m_f3;
    int m_f4;

    Features(int a, int b, int c, int d) :
        m_f1(a),
        m_f2(b),
        m_f3(c),
        m_f4(d)
    {

    }
};

int criterionFunction(Features const& features)
{
    return -2 * features.m_f1 * features.m_f2 +
            3 * features.m_f3 + 
            5 * features.m_f4 +
           -2 * features.m_f1 * features.m_f2 * features.m_f3 + 
            7 * features.m_f3 +
            4 * features.m_f4 +
           -2 * features.m_f1 * features.m_f2 * features.m_f3 * features.m_f4;
}

int main(){

    Features feature,
    vector<Features> listOfFeatures(4);

    listOfFeatures.push_back(Features(1,0,0,0));
    listOfFeatures.push_back(Features(0,1,0,0));
    listOfFeatures.push_back(Features(0,0,1,0));
    listOfFeatures.push_back(Features(0,0,0,1));

    vector<int> listOfCriterion;

}
```

My questions are:

**- What is the way to make a call to `criterionFunction()` such that which ever feature passed (i.e; m_f1) will take the value `1` and which are not passed will have the value `0`?**

**- Here, I want to select (my output) the combination of the best `three` features. How can I do that?**

Comment: Man, I will be honest. I'm a lazy programmer ... any time I see `matrix multiplication / summation / sequences or probability` I think straight in `Matlab` and I don't even try to start something in `C++` or `Java` unless I have to. Have you considered `Matlab` to accomplish your task?

Comment: possible duplicate of [If I pass a value I want it "1", otherwise, I want it "0". What do you think?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713452/if-i-pass-a-value-i-want-it-1-otherwise-i-want-it-0-what-do-you-think)

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear to me what your requirements are from your questions, however a general answer would be to use a C++ linear algebra library such as Armadillo:

http://arma.sourceforge.net/

This will give you a matrix class and associated operations, with a similar interface to MATLAB.